# python extract time from date column to plot

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have a CSV file and I've to extract only time as a seperate column. I tried several ways but couldn't do it properly. I've to use this time column to build a line plot. Any idea?

The date column format is:
2016-04-15 06:00:01.704

So my time column should end up as:
06:00

Example of how my dataset my look:

```
Date                          x1        x2          .....
2016-04-15 06:00:31.678 5.10165404238 12.2763408161,.....
2016-04-15 06:01:01.670 2.12747098266 10.9392058608,....
2016-04-15 06:01:31.675 3.8868992871   ....
```

SO here's how I'm intending to approach:
For each day plot the line graph for every minute. x axis ticks for every 15 minutes
Each graph will have time on x axis and one column on y axis

I can kind of loop them, but how to implement seems to be a challenge

I have to plot

Comment: x axis is datetimes. How about y axis?

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the date into a structure, so that you can get all the parts with ease (hour, day, year, minute, etc).
[Datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

If that "date column format" is the only data in each line of the CSV file, and if you have read in a line into variable `s`, you can extract the time with

```
time_column = s[11:16]
```

This will give the time as you stated, to the minute. However, this rounds the time down, not to the nearest minute. To round you could to check the character after the colon that comes after the minutes.

Comment: I've updated my post with more details.
Additionally, I don't think reading each row will be feasible. It might take a lot of time to complete

Answer (score 0):

First convert your timestamps to python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) using [datetime.strptime(date_string, format)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
import datetime

list_string = ['2016-04-15 06:00:01.704']
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
list_datetimes = datetime.datetime.strptime(list_string, fmt)
```

Then convert the datetimes to matplotlib format using [date2num](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num).

```
import matplotlib
x = matplotlib.dates.date2num(list_datetimes)
```

Now, you are able to plot using [plot_date](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot_date(x, y)
```

Limit x axis by using [xlim(...)](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xlim#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim).

```
plt.xlim(xmax=...)
```

Comment: Sounds good. I've updated my post. Would you be able to suggest

Answer (score 0):

For date and time operations in Python, I often use the arrow library. I find it much more intuitive to use than datetime or tz (even though arrow is built on top of the two, and others).

You can find its git page with API at https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow or of course you can also simply install it with

```
pip install arrow
```

You should then simply be able to do:

```
import arrow
arrow_object = arrow.get('2016-04-15 06:00:01.704')
time_str = arrow_object.format('HH:mm')
```

I you see the time is off by a couple of hours, that's probably because it is in UTC. Call

```
arrow_object.to('local')
```

before converting the time to a string. For more info check out the API docs. They're pretty good!